# getting value in Interger array using for loop

Tags: java, android

I am new to programming and started android few week back.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

int a,i,j,k;
 /*char [][] s1= new char[][]
 {
                                     {'A','B','C','D'},
                                     {'E','F','G','H'},
                                     {'I','J','K','L'},
                                     {'M','N','O','P'},
                                     {'Q','R','S','T'},
                                     {'U','V','W','X'},
                                     {' ','Y','Z',' '}};*/


char [][] s2=new char[8][8];
char[][] s3=new char[8][8];
int[] getlist=  new int[10];;
char choice,choice1;
int x,b,c,d;
String[] messageText = new String[10];
String[] messageEdit = new String[10];

public void letterNo(View view) { // Method to show screen for getting number of letters

    setContentView(R.layout.displaylettersno);
}

public void getNumber(View view) { // Method to get Numbers of Letter


    EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    String s = et.getText().toString();
    x = Integer.parseInt(s);


    if (x > 0 && x < 9) {

        et.setText("");
    } else {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong Entery... Enter again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
    setContentView(R.layout.gettingcolumnno);



   // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Click on Column No in Which 1st Letter Appear",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView8);
for (i = 0; i < x; i++){
    textView.setText("Enter Column No. in which Your letters of name is 
present:" );
}
}


public void buttondone(View view) {
   EditText op  = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.operator2);
    String num = op.getText().toString();


    for (i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {

        getlist[i] = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(op.getText()));

    }

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


}
```

I want to develop a Name guess game 
1- it will ask user to enter the no. of letters he thought 
2- it will ask user to enter the column no in which his letter present ( i want this to run according to user enter the no of letter . 
suppose user enter 4 digits and it will ask to enter the column no 4 times. 
and similarly it has a edit box where user enter column no . 
i am using for loop for this purpose but it only show 1 time i am stuck here for 1 week . help me if you understand what i am trying to do . following is my code

Answer (score 0):

Done button has to be pressed number of letters time to get columns.

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView8);
int numberOfColumnsEntered = 0;
public void getNumber(View view) {
   // get number logic then
   textView.setText("Enter Column No. "+(numberOfColumnsEntered+1)+" in which your letters appear");
}

public void buttondone(View view) {
    EditText op  = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.operator2);
    String num = op.getText().toString();
    getlist[numberofColumnsEntered] = Integer.parseInt(num);
    numberofColumnsEntered++;
    textView.setText("Enter Column No. "+(numberOfColumnsEntered+1)+" in which your letters appear");
    if(numberofColumnsEntered == x) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: How do i show a msg in textview " Enter the column in which your 1 letter appear ? " and letter no changes on every click of done button when click it ask for the 2nd letter so on

Comment: Please see the edit. Use a counter variable to count the number of columns entered by user.